# Changing SurfaceViews of MediaPlayer

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview, android-mediaplayer

I am attempting to change the SurfaceView of a MediaPlayer during playback. I am using the setDisplay method of MediaPlayer, but once the new Surface view is set, playback does not always continue at the same position before the new SurfaceView was set. I have looked on StackOverflow and other forums, and it appears that MediaPlayer suffers from many irregular behavior problems. Is it possible to switch SurfaceViews of a MediaPlayer without reloading the MediaPlayer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is not possible. I've had similar issues where setting the surface after playback has started results in a blank screen with sound.